# Как перезагрузить данные в ESelect2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

Есть виджет в yii 1:

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
            'name' => 'mySelect',
            'data' => $model->getData(),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
               'onchange' => '
                showDeleteBtn(this.value);
               ',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Выбери что хочешь удалить',
            ),
        ));
```

Вывожу данные и показываю кнопку методом showDeleteBtn(this.value). Удаляю, все норм, но как потом после удаления сделать refresh самого select-a или хотя бы выставить для него начальное положение "Выбери что хочешь удалить"

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось "докапываться" до классов селекта и вручную имитировать refresh

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'delete',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: 'id=' + activeStudentId,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#students option[value='" + activeStudentId + "']").remove();
                    $("a.select2-choice").addClass( "select2-default" ).find("span").html("Выбери что хочешь удалить");
                    cleanHide();
                }
            },
        });
```

после удаления